# function to push value to array on checkbox OR radio change

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have a function like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  array = [];
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() { 
    array.push($(this).val()); // push checked checkbox values to array
  });
  $('input:radio:checked').each(function() { 
    array.push($(this).val()); // push checked radio values to array
  });
  someOtherFunction();
});
```

... which collects values from checkboxes and radio buttons in one array. At the moment it runs when a checkbox changes but I want it to run when a radio button changes too.

As a noob I have no idea where to start so have tried very little. And I didn't find the answer after a good search.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have an example already, why don't you try to apply it to your radio buttons too?

Comment: Sounds simple, but I just didn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$('input:checkbox, input:radio').change(function() {
```

The problem is that your current selector is only applicable for checkboxes.

Comment: @nathangregg, I am happy it works. If my answer solved your problem, you may accept it, so users in the future having similar problems will be helped as well.